# Can't upgrade Laravel from 5.8 to 6

Tags: laravel, upgrade

I did upgrade from 5.6 to 5.7 to 5.8 with no major problems, but I CAN'T upgrade from 5.8 to 6. Let's see some code:

My composer.json file:

```
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "arcanedev/log-viewer": "~4.7.0",
        "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "5.x",
        "devmarketer/easynav": "^1.0",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^5.0",
        "kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2": "^1.0.0",
        "laracasts/flash": "^3.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^7.1",
        "nesbot/carbon": "2.61.0 as 1.39.0",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.2",
        "pragmarx/google2fa-laravel": "^0.2.0",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~3.0",
        "robbiep/cloudconvert-laravel": "2.*",
        "santigarcor/laratrust": "5.0.*",
        "sendgrid/sendgrid": "~7",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^4.1",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "^4.1",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.*",
        "unsplash/unsplash": "^2.4",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables": "^1.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "kylekatarnls/update-helper": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

And the error is:

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev].
    - arcanedev/log-viewer[4.7.0, ..., v4.7.x-dev] require arcanedev/support ~4.5.0 -> satisfiable by arcanedev/support[4.5.0].
    - arcanedev/support 4.5.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.8.36 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires arcanedev/log-viewer ~4.7.0 -> satisfiable by arcanedev/log-viewer[4.7.0, ..., v4.7.x-dev].
```

I've looked on every forum I found on the internet (almost did!) but couldn't find a solution or any hints on what I could be doing wrong.

What could be wrong? Any hints?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recentely upgraded from laravel 5.6 to 9 and the easiest way i found it was to make a new fresh copy of laravel 9 and use the composer json from that copy and added whatever extra i needed into it.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by the following:

- You want to install `laravel/framework:^6.0`, which comes with `illuminate/support:^6.0`.
- One of your dependencies, `arcanedev/log-viewer:~4.7.0` requires `arcanedev/support:~4.5.0`
- And finally, `arcanedev/support:~4.5.0` requires laravel's `illuminate/support:^5.8.0`.
- This creates a conflict.

You have 2 ways to resolve the conflict.

1. Keep laravel at version 5.8
2. Update the `arcanedev` dependencies to a version where they work with laravel 6.

Based on [`arcanedev/log-support`'s packagist page](https://packagist.org/packages/arcanedev/log-viewer#5.2.0), I think 5.2 should do it.

```json
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "arcanedev/log-viewer": "^5.2.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
    ...
```

This is because `arcanedev/log-viewer:^5.2.0` requires `arcanedev/support:^5.0` which in turn requires `illuminate/support:^6.0`, removing the conflict.

Comment: Hi @IGP, now the problem is with Laratrust@5 witch requires illiminate as you can see as fallows: ```santigarcor/laratrust[5.0.0, ..., 5.0.x-dev] require illuminate/support ~5.2 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.2.0,``` . There is an update to 6, and I hope this can solve the issue!

Comment: Every time I update a package, another one calls! I'm starting to think that upgrade is not doable!

Comment: This is what happens when you get too many dependencies in your project. By the way, I think you can safely remove `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet`. It should be installed alongside `maatwebsite/excel`

Comment: The earliest version for `santiagocor/laratrust` you could require is [^5.2.0](https://packagist.org/packages/santigarcor/laratrust#5.2.3)